# Odoo13 stuck on a blank page after login

Tags: odoo, odoo-13

After I logged in to my Odoo13,showing a blank page.
In my browser console am getting below error (in debug mode):

```
XML Parsing Error: unclosed token
Location: http://my_ip:8069/web/webclient/qweb/70e11af7eab110e061176f80e76afaae499cb597?mods=base,web,base_setup,bus,web_tour,mail,resource,mail_bot,hr,calendar,hr_holidays,hr_skills,barcodes,hr_attendance,report_xlsx,auth_signup,base_automation,fingent_disable_copy_paste,fingent_hr,fingent_pdf_viewer,fingent_hr_holidays,fingent_hr_remote_work,fingent_chat_bot,base_import,fingent_hr_theme,hr_org_chart,iap,partner_autocomplete,permit_export_module,sms,snailmail,web_diagram,web_editor,web_kanban_gauge,web_unsplash
Line Number 2421, Column 13: 70e11af7eab110e061176f80e76afaae499cb597:2421:13
XML Parsing Error: unclosed token
Location: http://my_ip:8069/web#cids=1
Line Number 2421, Column 13: web:2421:13
Uncaught (in promise) 
Object { readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: getResponseHeader(key), getAllResponseHeaders: getAllResponseHeaders(), setRequestHeader: setRequestHeader(name, value), overrideMimeType: overrideMimeType(type), statusCode: statusCode(map), abort: abort(statusText), state: state(), always: always(), catch: catch(fn)
, … }
4
info: Some modules could not be started boot.js:218:20
Rejected modules:         
Array [ "web_tour.tour" ]
boot.js:228:24
Rejected linked modules:  
Array [ "web_tour.DebugManager.Backend", "mail.tour" ]
boot.js:231:24
Debug:                    
Object { "web_tour.DebugManager.Backend": {…}, "mail.tour": {…}, "web_tour.tour": {…} }
boot.js:239:24
```

I am not getting any error in my terminal.
And this code is working fine in my local instance and testing instance.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Are you sure you rolled out every custom module mentioned in the error? I had some of those blank page situations and in the end it was missing (installed) modules, after making mistakes on deployment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Parsing Error: unclosed token`: I would first check the XML files in the modules mentioned in the error logs to make sure all the XML elements are correctly formatted and properly closed.

From the error log, it appears that there are several custom modules (like `fingent_disable_copy_paste`, `fingent_hr`, `fingent_pdf_viewer`, etc.). Try temporarily disabling these custom modules one by one to identify if any of them are causing the issue.
After making changes, do not forget to restart the Odoo server to apply the changes.

Though you mentioned that there are no errors in the terminal, it is advisable to double-check Odoo server logs for any warnings or errors that might give you a hint regarding the issue.

---

Check also for any configuration difference between your  local instance, testing instance and the instance where you see that error. [This thread](https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/getting-error-right-after-successful-login-to-odoo-201993) mentions for example:

> We had this bug when we activated the workers with a longpolling reverse proxy.